# Gesture Recognizer and UIImageView With Custom Property

Tags: swift

My app uses images which can have various statuses so I am using custom properties as tags. This works ok, but my tap gesture recognizer can't seem to access these properties. When the image is tapped, I need the action to depend on the state of these properties. Is there a way the gesture recognizer can read these custom properties from the tapped subclassed UIImageView or should I take a different approach? Thanks!

```
public class advancedTagUIImageView: UIImageView {
    var photoViewedStatus: Bool?
    var photoLikedStatus: Bool?
}

viewDidLoad() {
    let imageView = advancedTagUIImageView(frame:CGRect(origin: CGPoint(x:50, y:50), size: CGSize(width:100,height:100)))
    imageView.image = UIImage(named: dog.png)
    imageView.photoViewedStatus = false
    imageView.photoLikeStatus = false
    imageView.tag = 7
    imageView.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(soundTapped)))
    view.addSubview(imageView)
}

 @objc func soundTapped(gesture: UIGestureRecognizer) {
    let photoTag = gesture.view!.tag // this works great
    let isPhotoLiked = gesture.view!.photoLikeStatus // this doesn't work
    // do whatever 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Swift is strongly typed. The type of the `gesture.view` property is `UIView` which doesn't have the properties defined in your `advancedTagUIImageView` class. This is because you could theoretically also attach your `UITapGestureRecognizer` to any other type of view. In which case the program would crash on your `soundTapped` method, because you're just assuming that `gesture.view` is an `advancedTagUIImageView` which might not always be the case.

For the compiler to let you access these properties you need first check if `gesture.view` is really your sublcass like this:

```
if let photoView = (gesture.view? as? advancedTagUIImageView) {
    // you can access your tags here
    let isPhotoLiked = photoView.photoLikeStatus
} else {
    // you might want to handle the case that the gesture was invoked from another view. If you're certain this should not happen, maybe just throw an assertion error to get notified in case it still does.
}
```

PS: According to the Swift [API Design Guidelines](https://swift.org/documentation/api-design-guidelines/#general-conventions) type names should be capitalized, so in your case it should be `AdvancedTagUIImageView`. Not following these guidelines might not crash your program, but doing so might make your life a lot easier should you ever need to write code together with other people.

Comment: Okay, I understand now. Thank you very much! Great answer.

Comment: I will capitalize those type names from now on!